# Select ID from String variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I use a string to select an element by ID in asp.net C#?

I have a series of DropDownLists with similar IDs (red0, red1, red2 etc.). I want to select them & get their value by concatenating "red" with the counter in a variable within a for loop, so I can avoid writing out red0.Text red1.Text. I know how to do this in jQuery but cannot for the life of me find out how to in asp.net C#.

Comment: Code example please...

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to use reflection (not worth it) or create a data structure (`List` or `Array`) and initialize it to the various `DropDownList` members.

You could also use `FindControl` but like reflection it is going to be doing searching at runtime and isn't worth it.